# How do i add spinner inside listview row in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-spinner

I am developing an app in this i have populate `listview` with `json` parser. Now i have to add local spinner array inside this `listview` single row. 
How do i add locally spinner array inside this `listview` row. And also i want to get selected spinner values of `listview`. Following is my code please suggest me.

```
//activity
public class MyModifyPgmLvAddUserActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

            private DBManager dbManager;
            private ListView listView, listView1;
            Toolbar toolbar;
            private String TAG = MyModifyPgmLvAddUserAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
            private ProgressDialog pDialog;
            //    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
            MyModifyPgmLvAddUserAdapter1 adapter;


            static String RANK = "AsanaId";
            static String COUNTRY = "Asananame";
            static String POPULATION = "repetation";

            ArrayList<PojoList> SubjectList = new ArrayList<PojoList>();

            final static String[] mSpinnerItems = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"};

            private static String url = "http://www.test.com/ypAndroid/api/getDefaultProgramlist";
            String asananame, asanaid,duration, imageurl, imageversion, audiourl, audioversion, videourl, videoversion;

            String sid;
            boolean selected;
            String id;
            String[] subject = null;
            String[] spinner = null;
            String title;
            long id1;
            Button btnCreate;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_modifypgm_lv_add_user);

                btnCreate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_submit);

                dbManager = new DBManager(this);
                dbManager.open();


                Intent i = getIntent();
                id= i.getStringExtra("id");
                subject = i.getStringArrayExtra("subject");
                spinner = i.getStringArrayExtra("spinner");
                title= i.getStringExtra("title");

                id1= Long.parseLong(id);

                SubjectList = new ArrayList<>();

                listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

                //Net Connection
                ConnectivityManager conMgr =  (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo netInfo = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                if (netInfo == null){
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyModifyPgmLvAddUserActivity1.this);
                    //  new AlertDialog.Builder(MyModifyProgramEditDeleteActivity.this)
                    alert.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
                    alert.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet));
                    alert.setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();

                    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            //Do something here where "ok" clicked and then perform intent from activity context
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MyModifyPgmLvAddUserActivity1.this, MyYogaPosesSubMenuActivity.class);
                            MyModifyPgmLvAddUserActivity1.this.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
                    alert.show();
                }
                else {
                    new MyModifyPgmLvAddUserActivity1.DownloadJSON().execute();
                }


                btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        checkButtonClick();
                        Intent modify_intent = new Intent(MyModifyPgmLvAddUserActivity1.this, MyModifySavedProgramActivity1.class);
                        modify_intent.putExtra("subject", spinner);
                        modify_intent.putExtra("spinner", subject);
                        modify_intent.putExtra("id", id);
                        modify_intent.putExtra("title", title);
                        startActivity(modify_intent);

                    }
                });


            }

            private void checkButtonClick() {

                ArrayList<String> list1= new ArrayList<>();
                ArrayList<String> list2= new ArrayList<>();
             //   ArrayList<String> list3= new ArrayList<>();

                PojoList pojo = null;
                ArrayList<PojoList> countryList = adapter.SubjectListTemp;
                for (int i = 0; i < countryList.size(); i++) {

                    pojo = countryList.get(i);

                    if (pojo.isSelected()) {
                        // responseText.append("\n" + country.getName());

                        list1.add(pojo.getAsanName());

                      //  list2.add(convertArrayToString(subject));
                        list2.add(pojo.getAsanId());
                       // list2.add(convertArrayToString(spinner));

                    }
                }

                String [] aIds = list1.toArray(new String[list1.size()]);
                String [] aNames = list2.toArray(new String[list2.size()]);

                dbManager.update(id1, aIds, aNames);
                //   dbManager.insert(title, names, spinner);
                //  dbManager.set_datetime_next(id, names, spinner);
            }

            public static String[] convertStringToArray(String str){
                String[] arr = str.split(strSeparator);
                return arr;
            }

            private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

                private ProgressDialog pDialog;

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    // Showing progress dialog
                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyModifyPgmLvAddUserActivity1.this);
                    pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    pDialog.show();
                }

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                    HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
                    String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

                    PojoList pojo;

                    Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

                    if (jsonStr != null) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject o = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                            JSONArray restaurants = o.getJSONArray("getdefaultprogramlist");

                            for (int k = 0; k < restaurants.length(); k++) {

                                JSONObject rating1 = restaurants.getJSONObject(k);

                                asanaid = rating1.getString("programid");
                                Log.d("TestJson asanaid", asanaid);
                                asananame = rating1.getString("programname");
                                Log.d("TestJson asananame", asananame);

                                for (int i = 0; i < restaurants.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject restaurant = restaurants.getJSONObject(i);

                                    JSONArray ratings = restaurant.getJSONArray("ProgramItem");
                                    for (int j = 0; j < ratings.length(); j++) {

                                        JSONObject rating = ratings.getJSONObject(j);
                                        String stepnumber = rating.getString("AsanaId");
                                        Log.d("TestJson stepnumber", stepnumber);
                                        String stepdesc = rating.optString("Asananame");
                                        Log.d("TestJson stepdesc", stepdesc);
                                        String stepimg = rating.getString("duration");
                                        Log.d("TestJson stepimg", stepimg);
                                        String stepimgeversion = rating.getString("repetation");
                                        Log.d("TestJson stepimgvrsion ", stepimgeversion);


        //                               int sid = Integer.parseInt(convertArrayToString(mSpinnerItems));
                                        pojo = new PojoList(stepnumber, stepdesc, selected, convertArrayToString(mSpinnerItems));

                                        SubjectList.add(pojo);


                                        System.out.println("Size of Entry list from Map: " + SubjectList.size());

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                        .show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

                    if (pDialog.isShowing())
                        pDialog.dismiss();

                    adapter = new MyModifyPgmLvAddUserAdapter1(MyModifyPgmLvAddUserActivity1.this, R.layout.my_yoga_poseslv_add_user_single_item, SubjectList);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }


            public static String strSeparator = ",";
            public static String convertArrayToString(String[] array){
                String str = "";
                for (int i = 0;i<array.length; i++) {
                    str = str+array[i];
                    // Do not append comma at the end of last element
                    if(i<array.length-1){
                        str = str+strSeparator;
                    }
                }
                return str;
            }
        } 

    //PojoList
    public class PojoList {

        String AsanName = null;
        String AsanId = null;
        boolean selected = false;
        String sid = null;
        String sarray = null;
        boolean sSelected = false;

        public PojoList(String Sname, String SFullForm, boolean selected, String Sarray) {

            super();

            this.AsanName = Sname;

            this.AsanId = SFullForm;

            this.selected = selected;

            this.sarray = Sarray;

           // this.sid = Sid;
        }

        public String getAsanName() {

            return AsanName;

        }
        public void setAsanName(String code) {

            this.AsanName = code;

        }
        public String getAsanId() {

            return AsanId;

        }
        public void setAsanId(String id) {

            this.AsanId = id;

        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {

            return  AsanName + " " + AsanId ;

        }

        public boolean isSelected() {
            return selected;
        }
        public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
            this.selected = selected;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return sarray;
        }
        public void setId(String sarray) {
            this.sarray = sarray;
        }
    }
```

//adapter

```
public class MyModifyPgmLvAddUserAdapter1 extends ArrayAdapter<PojoList> {

    public ArrayList<PojoList> MainList;

    public ArrayList<PojoList> SubjectListTemp;

    Context context;


    private String[] mSpinnerItems = new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"};

    //  public ListAdapter.SubjectDataFilter subjectDataFilter ;

    public MyModifyPgmLvAddUserAdapter1(Context context, int id, ArrayList<PojoList> subjectArrayList) {

        super(context, id, subjectArrayList);

        this.SubjectListTemp = new ArrayList<PojoList>();

        this.SubjectListTemp.addAll(subjectArrayList);

        this.MainList = new ArrayList<PojoList>();

        this.MainList.addAll(subjectArrayList);
    }

    public class ViewHolder {

        TextView SubjectName, aId;
        TextView SubjectFullForm, aName;
        CheckBox cb;
        Spinner spinner;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.my_yoga_poseslv_add_user_single_item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.aName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listview_tv);

            holder.aId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listview_id);

            holder.cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listview_cb);

            holder.spinner = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listview_spinner);

            holder.cb.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ;
                    PojoList pojo = (PojoList) cb.getTag();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                            "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() +
                                    "Clicked on Checkbox: "+
                                    " is " + cb.isChecked() + "Id is : "+ pojo.getAsanName(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    pojo.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                }
            });

            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mSpinnerItems);
            holder.spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        PojoList pojo = SubjectListTemp.get(position);

        holder.aName.setText(pojo.getAsanName());

        holder.cb.setText(pojo.getAsanId());

        holder.cb.setChecked(pojo.isSelected());

        holder.cb.setTag(pojo);

        //  holder.spinner.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(pojo.getId()));
        holder.spinner.setSelected(pojo.isSelected());

        return convertView;

    }

}
```

//list row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#cccccc">


        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/listview_spinner"
            style="@style/AppTheme"
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="21dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="21dp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/listview_cb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listview_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="1sp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/listview_imgs"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/listview_imgs" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listview_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/listview_spinner"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/listview_spinner"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/listview_imgs"
            android:text="TextView" />



    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Does your ListView have a custom adapter, and row .xml?

Comment: too much code. Please remove non-relevant code.

Comment: use expandable  list view.

Comment: Yes i have other adapter class file in this xml of list row includes.

Comment: how do i add spinner inside at parse items?

Comment: Could you please update your question and include the adapter and list row xml?

Comment: @  SubjectList.add(pojo);  in code

Comment: yes i update my code with adapter class

Comment: @AndreasEngedal I added adapter code please suggest me

Answer (score 5):

I have created a basic project to show you how to setup a simple Spinner. This is my xml for the list row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:padding="20dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/row_item_textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/row_item_spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:padding="2dp" />
```

This is the adapter for the listview:

```
public class BasicSpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<String> mSpinnerItems;
private ArrayList<String> mData;
private Context mContext;

public BasicSpinnerAdapter(ArrayList<String> data, ArrayList<String> spinnerItems, Context context) {
    mData = data;
    mContext = context;
    mSpinnerItems = spinnerItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item_spinner, null);
    }

    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_item_textview);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.row_item_spinner);

    textView.setText(mData.get(position));
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mSpinnerItems);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}
```

And this is my Activity, where I start it all:

```
public class SpinnerListviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView lvSpinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.spinner_listview_activity);
    lvSpinner = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_spinner);

    ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<>();
    mData.add("Test1");
    mData.add("Test2");
    mData.add("Test3");
    mData.add("Test4");

    ArrayList<String> mSpinnerData = new ArrayList<>();
    mSpinnerData.add("1");
    mSpinnerData.add("2");
    mSpinnerData.add("3");
    mSpinnerData.add("4");

    BasicSpinnerAdapter adapter = new BasicSpinnerAdapter(mData, mSpinnerData, this);
    lvSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

The xml for my Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</ListView>
```

A screenshot of the Listview:
[image: Listview with Spinners]

Hope this gives you an idea of how to setup a basic Spinner in a List row. Feel free to ask any questions!

Comment: Please give me suggestions as per my code.I ahave use json parser to get data in listview and in this i have to add local spinner array. How do i do this?